# Ionic 2 public variable and internal function

Tags: javascript, function, angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm having an issue with Ionic 2 especially with angular. My problem is that i have a variable named "isConnected" and when I want to access from an internal function of a function, I can't. It says can't define proprety of undefined. How do I access to my variable isConnected from an internal function? I tried with this :    BleProvider.prototype.isConnected but it's not working. Someone can explain to me how this works please?

```
export class BleProvider {

 public isConnected = false;
 public mDevice;

 constructor(public http: Http) {}

 connectToDevice(device){
  console.log('Connecting to device...');

  this.mDevice = device;
  setTimeout(
   ble.connectToDevice(
    device,
    onConnected,
    onDisconnected,
    onConnectError),
   500);

  function onConnected(device) {
    console.log("Connected to device: " + device.name);
    this.isConnected = true;
    console.log("isConnected variable status: " + this.isConnected);
  }
  function onDisconnected(device) {
    console.log('Disconnected from device: ' + device.name);
  }
  function onConnectError(error) {
    console.log('Connect error: ' + error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), like this:

```
export class BleProvider {

    public isConnected = false;
    public mDevice;

    constructor(public http: Http) { }

    connectToDevice(device) {
        console.log('Connecting to device...');

        this.mDevice = device;

        // Create the callbacks by using arrow functions () => {...}
        let onConnected = (device) => {
                console.log("Connected to device: " + device.name);
                this.isConnected = true;
                console.log("isConnected variable status: " + this.isConnected);
            },
            onDisconnected = (device) => {
                console.log('Disconnected from device: ' + device.name);
            },
            onConnectError = (error) => {
                console.log('Connect error: ' + error);
            }

        // You can also use an arrow function in the setTimeout! :)
        setTimeout(() => {
            ble.connectToDevice(device, onConnected, onDisconnected, onConnectError);
        }, 500);

    }
}
```

When using a regular function, the `this` keyword references the function itself, but when using **arrow functions**, the `this` property is not overwritten and still references the component instance (where you defined the `isConnected` property).

Comment: Many thanks to you, you really helped me and clarified my mind here. Thank you very much

Comment: Maybe you can answer this question too :). In the same situation, if i want to call an external function after `this.isConnected = true;` like `this.myFunction();` (myFunction is declared outside of `connectToDevice()` it says : this.myFunction() is not a function.